# How to make a program that does something if the rx and tx line is disconnected?

Tags: arduino

I am writing a program and I have two Arduino's connected via the RX and TX pin, I want something to pop up on a screen when the two Arduino's disconnect from one another. Is there a way to do that without using (or using as little as possible) delays? If so, how?

I have already tried a lot of things and nothing that I could come up with worked. One worked but I then couldn't print anything on the screen (that one is the code provided).

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
int i = 0;
#define OLED_RESET 4
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_RESET);
int l = 0;
int p = 0;
#define NUMFLAKES 10
#define XPOS 0
#define YPOS 1
#define DELTAY 2
int k = 1;
#define DUUR   3700    // 15 x 60 x 1000 milliseconden
uint32_t timer;                   // 32 bits timer
int fukk = 0;
int test = 0;
#define LOGO16_GLCD_HEIGHT 16
#define LOGO16_GLCD_WIDTH  16
static const unsigned char PROGMEM logo16_glcd_bmp[] =
{ B00000000, B11000000,
  B00000001, B11000000,
  B00000001, B11000000,
  B00000011, B11100000,
  B11110011, B11100000,
  B11111110, B11111000,
  B01111110, B11111111,
  B00110011, B10011111,
  B00011111, B11111100,
  B00001101, B01110000,
  B00011011, B10100000,
  B00111111, B11100000,
  B00111111, B11110000,
  B01111100, B11110000,
  B01110000, B01110000,
  B00000000, B00110000
};

int incomingByte = 0;
int sad = 0;
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);
  display.clearDisplay();
  delay(500);
  display.clearDisplay();
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(p);

  display.display();
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(3);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(17, 16);
  display.print("Test");

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read the incoming byte:
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    p = i;

  }

  if (p == 99) {
    if (incomingByte == 0) {
      display.setTextSize(1);
      display.setTextColor(WHITE);
      display.setCursor(0, 0);
      display.print("No signal");
      display.display();
    }
  }
  incomingByte = 0;
}
```

Comment: Electrically, you cannot know if this RX/TX are disconnected. If you want to implement this, I would suggest to send a "heartbeat", like an "Hello\n" on the serial port every 2 or 3 seconds. If you don't receive any in 3 seconds, the port is disconnected.

Comment: But how do i do that? I mean like checking with a timer of 3 seconds

Comment: @RicardoAlves: That's not necessarily true. For instance PCIe **does** know if there is a receiver connected ot a tx-pair. Anyway, the question is far too broad for this site. I'd recommend OP do more basic research and define his problem **properly** before even thinking about a solution. As-is, it's just some half-cooked idea.

Comment: @Olaf If you use only RX TX cables, you cannot know eletrically. What PCe does is having probably on it's interface another cable connection that when plugged send a signal. With only RX/TX you cannot do that. Again, the approachj needs to be an heartbeat.

Comment: @RicardoAlves You can actually. The knowledge how-to tell the experts from the noob electrical engineers. And I'm not talking about PCs! /they don't use a special cable either) Anyway, this is neither the place nor the site to discuss this. The Q is way OT.

Comment: @Olaf You can't really. Can you really prove your argument?

Comment: @RicardoAlves: 1) I don't have to. 2) I already told you: a good EE could tell you. Unfortunately it's a dying species with all the kids pluging together Arduino-stuff thinking they are embedded devs. 3) Did you even read my comments? if you had, you would know what I'm up to. I gave some example, but there are easier ways, suitable for Arduino, too. (retorical question, I'll leave this discussion here finally, as it's neither the place, nor do I see any sense to put more time into it, as you apparently blocked your mind thinking already)

Comment: I am myself an electronic/embedded engineer working for a very known multinational company and I'm keen to know what ways are possible to with just two connections (RX / TX) you can know if those connections are unplugged. Very keen really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer the second question. how can you send a heartbeat from 1 arduino to the other It's pretty easy to do so say your heartbeat is  "...\n" you  set up a string listener to listen for a specific phrase so from one function you would set a heartbeat and a timer and from the second a string listener.

```
// first Arduino add function to the main loop of the first Arduino.

void send_Heartbeat() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.println("..."); //println sends"\n"
    //wait 3 seconds dont use delay it's blocking but
    //impliment a timer loop to count to 3 seconds.
  }
}


//second Arduino

//global variable
int counter = 3500;

void loop()
{

  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    String s = Serial.readStringUntil( /n);
    if (s == "...") {
      // reset counter to 3500ms
      // count down from 3500ms using a timer library
      if (counter == 0) {
        // print to LCD no signal
      }
      // do stuff
    }
  }
  // do more stuff
}
```